# Google Map API won't run unless I update Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

My app uses the Google Map API but when running the app I get a message saying `[app name] won't run unless you update Google Map services"`

I tried changing the Google Play services version in my gradle build but that didn't work.

Here is my gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ultramirinc.champs_mood"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner       "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
 }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-    core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ultramirinc.champs_mood">


<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.

     <permission
    android:name="ultramirinc.champs_mood.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"

-->
<uses-permission android:name="ultramirinc.champs_mood.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name= ".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ScheduleAdder"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_schedule_adder"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->

    <activity
    android:name=".MapsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"/>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: it's talking about the Google play service on your phone ... not your app

Comment: update your phone google play service and run again.